# derivative of vector using prime symbol

Tags: math-mode, vector

The problem is shown on the picture. I want to use prime symbol for derivative of vector, but as you can see, it doesn't look well (prime symbol and vector arrow are 'glued' together). What would be the easiest way to fix it?

[image: derivative of vector]

Comment: I would just add `\,` before the prime.  This could be achieved in a macro with `\def\primevec#1{\vec#1\,'}`

Comment: Apparently, this is angular momentum and the relevant derivative is respect to time, not space, so a dot should be used instead of a prime, from a Physicist's view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Physicist's view I suggest both the usage of `esvect` (font) package and `\dot` instead of primes, since the relevant equation contains a time derivative.

The `esvect` provides distinctive vector arrows, the relevant command is `\vv` instead of `\vec`, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\newcommand{\dotvec}[1]{\dot{\vv{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \vv{h}  = \vv{r} \times \vv{v} = \vv{r} \times \dotvec{r} \]



\end{document}
```

[image]